# Cannot find database driver: org.h2.Driver while running via tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, h2, liquibase

this question is asked in many places, but the solutions provided there haven't solved the problem for me. I'm using the liquibase as datasource, javax rest service and h2 database. And I'm using this class instead of web.xml. I had added the h2 jar file in both web-inf and lib in tomcat(version 9.0) in Linux.

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ApiConfig extends Application {

    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.package");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this? I know, I have missed something, kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: Should go in WEB-INF/lib, not WEB-INF

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion. But the error is while initiating the database via the liquibase. Need to fix that. Will fix that and update.

Comment: Are you talking about compile errors (during development) or runtime errors?

Comment: I'm confused. Nothing in your question suggests that you are requesting a database connection. If you want Tomcat to provide a `DataSource`, you need configuration for that. Presumably, if liquibase is providing a DataSource, it needs to be similarly-configured. Please post that configuration instead of seemingly unrelated code.